# Implementing the "default" behavior for a custom class (only one item may be active at any given time)

Tags: prestashop

I'm building a Video module that associates an URL with a title (it's as simple as it gets), but I need it to enforce a "default" behavior in which only one item may be active at any given time. Prestashop's miserable documentation will be the death of me...

The code for this mini-endeavor can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313782/associating-an-item-to-multiple-other-items-of-a-different-class-using-prestas) (on another SO question I was struggling with).

My idea was to run an SQL query in the postProcess function inside the AdminVideo controller for the backoffice. Here - and after the insertion/update - I would fire an SQL query that would set the value of the "active" column on all the other rows to 0.

My problem is that this function - postProcess() - gets called again and again (including when the videos need to be listed) and the query can't run everytime.

I've been struggling with this issue for the whole day and don't know what to do next.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there another method I can overload  in order to easily fire an SQL query everytime a row is updated/created?

Are there any decent books on this subject for version 1.5? It's really frustrating to spend more time looking for answers in SO that doing some actual work.

Thanks, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for the submit button in your _postProcess function.
For example, have a look at the _postProcess function of the bankwire module, in the `modules/bankwire/bankwire.php` script:

```
private function _postProcess() {
  if (Tools::isSubmit('btnSubmit')) {
    Configuration::updateValue('BANK_WIRE_DETAILS', Tools::getValue('details'));
        ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, ok but the bankwire module doesn't appear to have a backoffice admin panel at all (and I really need it). Pasting the Tools::isSubmit in the postProcess() function inside the adminvideo.php controller doesn't really work, nor can the code for the bankwire module be easily adapted (again, the backoffice)..

Comment: Enzino, one more thing: I can't seem to get the value for anything using Tools::getValue (it's always null I believe). I'm posting the full code here - http://pastebin.com/djutQPV7 -, any idea what i'm doing wrong? Thanks for all the help for the past few days... Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Hal The `Tools::getValue` method returns false when there is no $_POST or $_GET element with the specified key. Try adding the statement `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_REQUEST,true).'</pre>';` into your `postProcess()` function, just to see if the variable that you're looking for is effectively set.

Comment: Nailed it, it was a simple matter of converting it to string: (string)Tools::getValue('title') :)